# How to declare a variable with index from script in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, variables, jmeter

My goal is to find the way how to define a variable i got from script with index. For instance like d1..dn so i could use it further in test steps referring to them like ${d1}

```
//${proparray} = [5787,76380,54418,21856,35229]
///log.info (${proparray}.length)
var arraylength = ${proparray}.length -1 
for (var i = 0; i < arraylength ; i++ )
{
this ["element"+[i+1]] = ${proparray}[i]
}
```

I managed to define variables element[i+1] in the script, but how transfer it outside the script to variable with corresponding index. I suspect i should use vars.put somehow but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to define the variables in JMeter like you do in JavaScript you can use any [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following code:

```
def proparray = [5787, 76380, 54418, 21856, 35229]

proparray.eachWithIndex { number, idx ->
    vars.put('d' + idx, number as String)
}
```

It will create the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image: JMeter Define Variables]

You will be able to access them in "normal" test elements as i.e. `$d1` or in JSR223 Test Elements as `vars.get('d1')`

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was looking for